# Class "phpseclib3\File\ASN1" not found

Tags: php, phpseclib

I try to work with phpseclib library, but got an error message when I call method

**ASN1::decodeBER($ber);**

**local.ERROR: Class "phpseclib3\File\ASN1" not found {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Class "phpseclib3\File\ASN1" not found at D:\phpProjects\signAPI\app\Http\Controllers\sign\SignParser.php:284)**

but I have this library and phpStorm see this.

How can I solve this problem?

I tried update library but this can't help.

Comment: Did you install phpseclib with Composer? Did you do `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` at the top of the PHP file in question? And if you did install phpseclib with composer did you install v3 or some other version?

Answer (score 1):

I installed phpseclib not used composer that's way I get this error.
Problem was solved after intalled phpseclib using composer command

**composer require phpseclib/phpseclib:~3.0**